# Swift: Public Skscene not presenting with filenamed?

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, swift-playground

Ok, I am working in Swift playgrounds here and cannot figure out how to present an SkScene that is another class. So far I have placed this SKScene file, GameScene.swift, in my Sources folder and made it public.

In my main playground file I have tried:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground
import Foundation


let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 600) //view size
let view = SKView(frame: frame)

let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
//scene.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue


view.presentScene(scene)
view.showsFPS = true;
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Along with any other answer I could find on stack overflow. Nothing is working - the playground timeline is just a blank grey and this is output:

[image]

Is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it i possible, but at the moment your Gamscene object is nil. This is because `GameScene(filenamed: "" )` only works when you have the scene builder. Wish your not using in Xcode.

Instead. Use

```
GameScene(size: CGSize)
```

and make sure you create the game scene with

```
    class GameScene : SKScene {
       override sceneDidLoad() {
           super.sceneDidLoad()



    }

 }
```

after that present your scene from a view

```
    let sceneSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 550)
    let scene = GameScene(size: sceneSize)
    let viewRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 550)
    let skView = SKView(frame: viewRect)
    skView.presentScene(scene)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skView
```

Thats an example to get you started ^^